# DynamicObject's dynamic property does not bind

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I have a class that inherits from DynamicObject that has, in addition to dynamic properties, some statically defined properties. The statically defined properties bind in a `DataTemplate` without a problem - but not dynamic properties.

I'm using Silverlight for WP8 - not sure if this is the same issue for WPF.

Is binding supported for DynamicObjects?

**EDIT**: here's excerpt from the code:

The `DynamicObject` class `ItemContent`:

```
public class ItemContent : DynamicObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> propertyBag = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    // Statically-defined Property
    public string SProperty { get; set; }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        return propertyBag.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        if (propertyBag.ContainsKey(binder.Name)){
            propertyBag[binder.Name] = value;
        } else {
            propertyBag.Add(binder.Name, value);
        }

        RaisePropertyChanged(binder.Name);

        return true;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        return propertyBag.Keys;
    }
// ... omitted for brevity
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SProperty}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DProperty}"/>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

excerpt from ViewModel:

```
dynamic i1 = new ItemContent() { SProperty = "static property" };
i1.DProperty = "dynamic property";

ObservableCollection<ItemContent> Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemContent>(){ i1 };
```

Comment: It's supported.  Post code if you want more help.

Comment: @mdm20, I added the relevant sections of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a bug in Silverlight.

[Here's the report.](https://web.archive.org/web/20120622113418/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522119/databinding-to-dynamic-objects-is-broken)

The "Workarounds" tab of that page contain 4 different workarounds, each with its pros and cons.